# color of scrollbars within the page

Tags: css, web, scrollbar

I need help. My main page has a long table that will typically be approximately 2 screens "tall" (assuming a 1024x768 browser window).

I want

- the user to be able to browse that table up and down, while always having a set of control buttons available in the currently visible portion of the page.

AND

- to retain control over the color scheme of all elements on the page.

The problem is that both solutions I could think of that address the first point (using an overflown div or a frame) involve scrollbars that I cannot style. (At least on Firefox they will invariably be gray.)

I cannot implement a "pager" which breaks the data on the table into chunks which are served one at a time (eg, having a "next 40 results" link at the bottom). The user needs to refer to the full table to find and compare multiple rows throughout the table.

What are my options? My head hurts when I think of moving this entire page to Flash for this reason...

thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would use jquery and a scrollable div.

Here are some resources to get you started.
http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/scrollable/vertical.html

http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/vertical.html

Comment: @kieran! amazing! that is exactly what I was looking for. Jquery rocks. : )

Comment: Most artificial scrollbars have poor usability compared to the real thing; many are actively hostile to both usability and accessibility. Use with extreme caution. Used just to change the colour of a scrollbar, it is not a win.

Comment: The http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/using-jquery-slider-to-scroll-a-div tutorial doesn't take the mouse wheel into account, which could be quite frustrating for some users. If you use a library such as jScrollPane, MooScroll, or MooScroller, this is all taken care of for you.

Comment: I would second that notion of not using them. If you need scrollable content let the browser control it. Fixed size websites are pretty lame when you are looking at it on a larger monitor as you don't get to use up the available real estate on the screen. That said however I am not a designer I only get to build what has been given to me.

Answer (score 1):

**Don't** change the styling of scrollbars unless you **really** know what you're doing! However, if you understand the usability implications (and try to make them as user-friendly as possible), try the following options:

If you use jQuery, try [jScrollPane](http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/jScrollPane/jScrollPane.html).
If you use MooTools, try [MooScroll](http://greengeckodesign.com/?q=mooscroll) or [MooScroller](http://www.clientcide.com/wiki/cnet-libraries/08-layout/02-mooscroller).

The following StackOverflow threads might also be useful:

[How do I change the browser's scrollbar colours using CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784053/how-do-i-change-the-browsers-scrollbar-colours-using-css/)
[What's the deal with CSS and scroll bars?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/526488/whats-the-deal-with-css-and-scroll-bars/)
[How can one use scroll bar images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729713/how-can-one-use-scroll-bar-images/)

Comment: @Steve, many thanks! jScrollPane seems to prepackage exactly the functionality I need. I understand the concerns you mention; but as in one of the threads you linked to the native scrollbars simply destroy all effort put into creating a consistent application look-and-feel.

Comment: @laramichaels: Glad to be of help! :) The look-and-feel factor is definitely one of the main reasons to use custom scrollbars—sometimes the default scrollbars just don't fit in...